# spawn world after gzserver start

Tags: gazebo-world, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know if it's possible to spawn a world (sdf .world file) once gazebo is launched.
I tried to use the service `/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model` but I got this error: `GazeboRosApiPlugin SpawnModel Failure: input xml format not recognized` (I was loading the default `willowgarage.world`).

Did someone has already succed to spawn a world after gzserver startup?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17515/spawn-world-after-gzserver-start/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2845/guillaumeb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you don't give Gazebo a world on startup, it will load `empty.world`. Unfortunately, "closing" a world and opening a new one is not supported yet. So the answer is no, but that doesn't mean someone can't have found a hacky way of doing it.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0